# Are my Github Lists public? How can we organize our repositories for public?

Tags: github, repository

In Github we have option to organize our repos in lists. Are this list public so that anyone can see this lists.
If not how can I organize all repos so that it will be easy for public viewer to explore all repos.
Is there any option than lists?

I basically want to keep my github account organized for public view.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this post by Github Docs](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/exploring-projects-on-github/saving-repositories-with-stars#organizing-starred-repositories-with-lists), You can add private repositories to your lists but will only appear to people who also have read access to that repository and yes i do believe your lists will be public but we might get a private option as discussed in this [repo](https://github.com/community/community/discussions/8766)